# Repeat Click Function Cloning Div's After One Click jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Following on from a previous question, I now have a function that creates div's after a click using clone and places them randomly on the page.

I would however also like to be able to click the button once, and then a set amount of div's be created one after the other, without having to press the button more than once. So click the button once and then 10 of the div's are created randomly on the page, one after the other. As if someone was clicking the button.

I've tried using setInterval, but I could only get as far as delaying the time between the click and the actual div appearing. I considered use of for loops and tried noodling around, but that didn't get me anywhere either.

Thank you for any help!

```js
{
  $(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
      let bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      let bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
      let randPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth);
      let randPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyHeight);

      let $clone = $(".words:first").clone().appendTo("body");
      $clone.css({
        left: randPosX,
        top: randPosY,
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.words {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1 class="words">
    Hello!
  </h1>
  <button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: A `for` loop is exactly what you want. Why didn't it work? Show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need to define a new `setInterval()` call which contains the current logic to create the `h1` elements in random locations. All it needs is an additional check to see how many elements have already been added to the DOM. If it's 10 or more, call `clearInterval()` to stop any more being created.

```js
$(function() {
  let interval;
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if ($('.words').length >= 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }     
        
      let bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      let bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
      let randPosX = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyWidth);
      let randPosY = Math.floor(Math.random() * bodyHeight);

      let $clone = $(".words:first").clone().appendTo("body");
      $clone.css({
        left: randPosX,
        top: randPosY,
      });
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.words {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="words">
  Hello!
</h1>
<button class="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I was actually slightly close on this one. I had the interval timing in the correct place and I'd started with the setInterval in the same place, but I had no idea about the clearInterval needing to be before it... I'd even created a similar loop with the .length, but I'd have been days trying to get it in the right order! On another note you have literally saved my life today! You have no idea, Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)